# Conversion of C++ to Fortran 90

Tags: c++, fortran, code-translation

Is there a tool that converts C++ code into fortran? Please state any possible deficiency of the tool you use.

I know it sounds silly but I do have a C++ code that calls a big Fortran code inside and I need to to use OpenMP. I am trying to keep the parallel region only inside Fortran (because there are many `COMMON` blocks and `EQUIVALENCE`s used) so I have to translate a few hundreds of lines of C++ functions to Fortran.

Comment: The answer is simple. No there is not any. You translate it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the compiler (such as the GNU compilers), you're actually able to compile C, C++, Fortran, etc. code together. This is so you don't actually have to translate or rewrite that code. [C++ Forum Answer](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/95100/)

Comment: In fact compiling together is what I am doing here. The problem is that I cannot initiate all the variables used in the FORTRAN parallel region in the C++ part beforehand. Therefore I have to keep the parallel part in Fortran only.